# Правильность написания класса

Tags: php, классы

При вызове методов пишет: "не найден метод". В чем может быть ошибка?

```
<?php
class c_string
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content="";
    }
    public function append($_content)
    {
        $this->content.=$_content;
    }
};
class InstallForm extends c_string
{

    public function __construct()   
    {
        //$text.append("<table>");

        $this->text="<table>";
        //$content.append("");
        //$content.append("</table>");

    }
    function addElem($field_caption,$input_type,$input_value,$input_name)
    {
        //$text.append("<tr><td>$field_caption:</td><td><input type=\"$input_type\" value=\"$input_value\" name=\"$input_name\"></td></tr>");
        $this->text.=("<tr><td>$field_caption:</td><td><input type=\"$input_type\" value=\"$input_value\" name=\"$input_name\"></td></tr>");
    }
    public function End()
    {
        $this->text.=("</table>");
        return $this->text;
    }

};

$tmp  = new InstallForm();
$tmp.addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp.addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp.addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
echo $tmp.End();

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В РНР надо так:

```
$tmp  = new InstallForm();
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
echo $tmp->End();
```

Объектная модель хоть и напоминает Java, но синтаксис здесь другой

Comment: спасибо;;;;;

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp  = new InstallForm();
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
$tmp->addElem("sadsa","text","sdfdsf","test1");
echo $tmp->End();
```

Вызываете неправильно. И еще, ниразу не видел чтоб в конце класса ставили ;, хотя так тоже работает.

Comment: спасибо. это ко мне из плюсов пришло.